# generic claases so that further any class can call it and get object

Tags: java

I have designed the following interface:

```
public interface applyBuisnessRule {    
    public String execute(String jobCode)throws Exception;
}
```

and there are classes implementing it:

```
public class AccelImpl implements applyBuisnessRule {

    private static final String Success = null;

        @Override
        public String execute(String jobCode) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Success;
        }

    }
```

the other one is:

```
public class CardvaletImpl implements applyBuisnessRule {
    private static final String Success = null;

    public String execute(String jobCode) throws Exception {
        return Success;
    }

}
```

Please advise how can i make the below interface and class as more generic means the input parameter will be of string type but the return will be of object type so please advise how can i make it more generic one and it should return the object type as below we can clearly see that it is a stratergy design pattern but there is no generics in code

what I have tried is shown below also please advise is it the correct approach

the interface

```
interface applyBuisnessRule<T> {
    public T execute(String jobCode) throws Exception;
}
```

the class

```
class CardvaletImpl<T> implements applyBuisnessRule<T> {
    private static final String Success = null;

    public T execute(String jobCode) throws Exception {
        T result = null;
         // put your logic and populate result here. I believe you are not going to return Success every time as it String
        return result;
    }
}
```

code excecution

```
CardvaletImpl<String> cardvaletImpl = new CardvaletImpl<>();
String result = cardvaletImpl.execute("JOBCODE");
```

folks please advise can we further improve the solution or not

Comment: What's your problem? Your current one is fine

Comment: so the generics solution that I have added at last is fine, Thanks